# What's wrong with this simple script?

Tags: go

I study functions, wrote a simple script for the textbook, and there were 2 errors.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func zero(x int) {
    x = 0
    return x
}
func main() {
    x := 5
    x = zero(x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

> too many arguments to return (string return x)

How is "too many"? It's only one!

> zero(x) used as value (string x = zero(x))

I don't understand what he says to me.

Comment: You forgot to specify the return type.

Comment: 1) It's not a script. 2) Your errors tell you exactly what's wrong. Did you read them?

Comment: Being snarky won't convince people to help you. That said, a simple Google search for "go functions" should give you the hint you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int in func

```
package main
import "fmt"

func zero(x int) int {
    x = 0
    return x
}
func main() {
    x := 5
    x = zero(x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func zero(x int) int {
    x = 0
    return x
}

func main() {
    x := 5
    x = zero(x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is closer to the original idea...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func zero(x *int) {
    *x = 0
    return
}

func main() {
    x := 5
    zero(&x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`too many` means that your function is returning more values that the function signature specifies.

In your case, your function signature `func zero(x *int)`, says that this function doesn't returns ANY params, and inside the function body, you're returning ONE value: `return x`. So `1` is `too many` for `0` expected. Exactly 1 more.

Then `zero(x) used as value` is telling you that you're calling a function that doesn't return ANY value, and you're trying to assign the non-existent return value to a variable: `x = zero(x)`.

That's why the compiler tells you about using `zero(x)` as a value